# A way to get the content on selected text from mouse through te OS API

Tags: c++, linux, macos, operating-system

Is there a way to get the content on selected text from mouse in any application through the API of operating system (`Linux`/`OSX`) in `C`/`C++`? I know that exist the `xsel` program on Linux, but exist a `xsel` API? I don't wanna use the `excve`/`excvp` call.

Thanks!

Comment: look at pbcopy and xclip. These are clip board managers.

Comment: you can check out the source tarball for xsel. only 3 files are important: xsel.h, xsel.c and xsel.1x
xsel.1x = details about the working of this tool

Comment: Thanks @TommyDDD! But there a API from these managers? Or the usage as developer is just with `excve`?

Comment: Okay @technusm1, i will check theses files on xsel source code! Thanks a lot

Comment: @gustavosobral you could go that route, it sounds like a lot of work but you could set up a pipe and fork a process. Once pbcopy has read in data you then pipe it back to your main proc.